# Cutting a quote to fit page

Tags: environments, page-breaking, minipage, page, quotation

I'm writing my thesis and I have encountered the following problem: whenever I have a long quote to make, `LaTeX` tries to squeeze the entire quote in one page, leaving long blank spaces. I'm using the following commands to make the quotes:

```
{\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
        \vspace{5pt}
        {\small}\\
        }
        {   \vspace{5pt}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
}
```

Is there any way in which I could cut the quote without leaving blank spaces?

Comment: Please post a full, self-contained MWE.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the ready-made `quotation` environment?

Comment: As I comment below there is no particular reason other than not been familiar with the environment. I'll give it a try since it looks more simple than the minipage envieronment.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the ready-made `quotation` environment to typeset the long quote. E.g., adapting the code in [@Celdor's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652776/5001), I'd write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\begin{document}

\kant[1][1]
\begin{quotation}
  \setstretch{1.0}
  \kant[1-5]
\end{quotation}
\kant[3][1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have never use the quotation environment before. I'm just begining and, somehow, I learn to have long quotes  using the minipage environment. I would give a try to your method. It seems simpler!!

Comment: @PabloPiccoPlencovich - A serious drawback of using `minipage` environments for longer quotations is that page breaks are not possible inside a `minipage`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `list` environment with options to set left and right margins as well as any other paragraph settings, s.a. line spread, paragraph indentation and paragraph skip

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]
\begin{singlespacing}%
    \begin{list}{}{\rightmargin 1cm\leftmargin 1cm}%
        \parindent=1em\parskip=0pt
        \item\relax%
        \kant[1-5]
    \end{list}
\end{singlespacing}
\kant[3][1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Celdor!! It corrects it perfectly. Thank you again

Comment: Np. I can see @Mico has come with an already defined macro, whose effect seems to be exactly what you expect. You should definitely prefer already made built-in solutions over hacking snippets. Mine is only a workaround, which I should have mentioned in the first place, whilst `quotation` may have important guards preventing from unexpected issues when macro is used in different surroundings.